# match empty rows in csv file through regex

Tags: java, regex, csv

I have csv file with below data How I can remove empty rows in java through regex I tried using `^,+$` but Its not working

"Temp-A007","Default","Importing","","",""

"","",""

Comment: How is this data stored? `Array`, `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`

Comment: No ,It as a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "empty" row will have at most commas, quotes, and spaces, no?  How about:

```
^[", ]*$
```

?

Comment: thnx fr reply but not working

Comment: It might be correct but I am not able to write this expression in double quote getting compile error in java .I am tring String.replace("^[", ]*$","')

Comment: Sure.  Just escape the backslashes: "^[\", ]*$"

Comment: Thnx Its working . :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through RegEx. Simply use `input.replaceAll("(\"\\s*\"\\s*,?)", "");`

**Output**

```
input  : "Temp-A007", "","Default","Importing","","","" 
output : "Temp-A007", "Default","Importing",
```

**Code**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = new String("\"Temp-A007\", \"\",\"Default\",\"Importing\",\"\",\"\",\"\" ");
        String output = input.replaceAll("(\"\\s*\"\\s*,?)", "");

        System.out.println("input  : " + input);
        System.out.println("output : " + output);

    }
}
```